Translate dataset in fmx
I am working on a desktop application using fmx framework and I add multiple languages to it (I used Tlang component to do so ) to translate any label or text inside the application but I run to a unexpected behavior everything is getting translated correctly except the data that is called from database (I am using firedac component to connect to the database)
It seems that the Tlang component doesn't effect the data displayed in the grid at all
What I was wanted to happen is to translate some of the data that are displayed in the grid after I call them from the table of the data base (for example I have a column that describe the condition of the product: good , damaged ,out of stock (EN )
The expected behavior is
Good =bien , damaged = on dommage, out of stock = rapture de stock
